# ERROR: ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Tags: oracle

during connection on win 7 64 bit OS this errors was occurred.

oracale 11g ex
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Comment: You will have to give a lot more context/description to get an anser to this.

Answer (score 0):

That means the database you're trying to connect to is not up.